# Identify correct words from mixed up string (unexpected spaces in random places)

Tags: javascript, c#, text

The problem I got is: I might received strings from other systems, and there might be some unnecessary spaces inside the string, for example: "effec tive da te", it should be "effective date", so is it possible to have a generic algorithms which could remove this kind of incorrect spaces?.

I have tried RegExp, but the problem is the spaces could appeared inside any word, another example is: "no t all field s apply to all scenari os - provide onl y the necessary data"

Could anyone provide some suggestions?

JS or C# solution is highly preferred.

Comment: Naive solution, have a dictionary of English words, if a word isn't included in the dictionary, check to see if removing spaces around it results in a proper word

Comment: see `no t all field s` could be `not all fields` or `no tall fields` ... so, the simple answer is, it won't be easy

Comment: if number of this _"strings from other systems"_ are limited, you may store them in a dictionary, so "somestringfromothersystem" -> "some string from other system". Then, when you receive a string, you strip all whitespaces and look in that dictionary.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, yes, this is actually out initial thought, but just Jaromanda mentioned, it really won't be easy, we even doubt if it worth to do it if we "corrected" many words to wrong.

Comment: @vasily.sib, no, it's not limited, you can consider it as a bad OCR engine, the input for them is not limited, the output is also not limited.

Comment: If there is no header with the number of space, the easiest way will be google, submit the sentense accept the suggestion correction the search term if the difference is just space. It could also work with spell lib.

Comment: How do you know if a space is correct or incorrect?

Comment: @DragandDrop, that might be a solution, but I'm not sure if google has this kind of API, will try some spell lib, thank you :)

Comment: @MelGerats basically if a space breaks a word, it should be an incorrect space, for example: "effec tive", the space in this string will be incorrect since it breaks the word "effective" and produces two meaningless combinations of characters, but there might need some more advanced algorithms, please refer to Jaromanda 's comment, the spaces after "no" could be correct if you think the whole sentence should be "no tall fields", but it should be incorrect because the sentence "not all fields" is more meaningful than "no tall fields". So actually

Comment: @MelGerats continue my previous comment. actually I'm not quite sure if this is just spelling check issue, or requires some advanced technologies like NLP, that's why I posted this question here to get more thoughts from you clever guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to strip all spaces and apply a word segmentation algorithm to split the continuous stream of letters in a sequence of words that makes sense.

[This blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/fast-word-segmentation-for-noisy-text-2c2c41f9e8da) describes various techniques, and [this github project](https://github.com/wolfgarbe/SymSpell) provides an implementation.